# How to save results of lenghty calculation with multiple parameters?

Tags: python, numpy, save

I am doing some lengthy calculations with multiple parameters. I would like to save and retrieve the results of these calculations. I know how to save numpy arrays with pickle, but I am not sure of how to efficiently encode the parameters used for calculating these arrays.

As an example I have a function which calculates eigenvalues of large matrices. Depending on the parameters used to construct the matrix I get different eigenvalues. Now I would like to save the eigenvalues that I got with the specific combination of `dim, parameterA, parameterB, parameterC`. I could try to encode the parameters in the filename, but this quickly leads to very long file names as I have many more parameters in my real code. Any ideas of how to approach this?

```
import numpy                                                                                                   


def calculate_eigenvalues(dim, parameterA, parameterB, parameterC):                                            
    numpy.random.seed(parameterA)                                                                              
    matrix = numpy.random.uniform(parameterB, parameterC, (dim,dim))                                           
    eigenvalues = numpy.linalg.eigvals(matrix)                                                                 
    return eigenvalues                                                                                         


def magic_save(dim, parameterA, parameterB, parameterC):                                                       
    eigenvalues = calculate_eigenvalues(dim, parameterA, parameterB, parameterC)                               
    SAVE(eigenvalues)                                                                                          


def magic_load(dim, parameterA, parameterB, parameterC):                                                       
    LOAD(eigenvalues)                                                                                          
    return eigenvalues                                                                                         


# calculate and save eigenvalues                                                                               
magic_save(dim=4, parameterA=2, parameterB=-3.2, parameterC=4.1)  # calculates and saves eigenvalues           

# calculate and save some other eigenvalues for different parameters                                           
magic_save(dim=8, parameterA=23, parameterB=-3.1, parameterC=0.1)  # calculates and saves eigenvalues          

# retrieve eigenvalues for a certain combination of parameters                                                 
loaded_eigenvalues = magic_load(dim=4, parameterA=2, parameterB=-3.2, parameterC=4.1)    # loads saved eigenvalues
calculated_eigenvalues = calculate_eigenvalues(dim=4, parameterA=2, parameterB=-3.2, parameterC=4.1)           

# compare that the result is really the same:                                                                  
print(f"loaded and calculated eigenvalues are identical:"                                                          
      f"{numpy.allclose(loaded_eigenvalues, calculated_eigenvalues)}")
```

Comment: You want to save them using pickle? Why not use the numpy functions for saving/loading arrays?

Comment: I am perfectly fine using `numpy.savez`. Thanks for pointing it out. I had a look at the documentation again and saw that I can do `numpy.savez('filename.npz', dim=dim, parameterA=parameterA, parameterB=parameterB, parameterC=parameterC)`. However, I still need a suitable filename so I can retrieve my results. I do not intend to do all the calculations at once, but add more over time. Any ideas how to use numpy in this case?

Comment: Only think I can think of is the method suggested by mcsoini, which I believe could be combined with the use of `numpy.savez`.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that in my limited experience, `savez` can be a tad slow. How many arrays are we talking about here? How large?

Comment: Maybe a couple hundred arrays (files). Each array is one dimensional and has a maximum of 5000 entries, preferably less (eigenvalue computation is slooow). So I guess the speed of `savez` should not be too big of an issue.

Comment: Nah, that sounds fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could calculate a hash from all parameter values (possibly including the parameter names), and use that as a filename. Like this you can be rather certain that you obtain unique filenames for each parameter value combination, while keeping the filename length concise and consistent.

```py
from hashlib import md5

def get_filename(*params):

    fn = md5('_'.join(map(str, params)).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[:10]
    return fn + '.pickle'

params = [1.2, 3, 4, 'abc']
get_filename(params)
# out: '4d2e889a15.pickle'
```

Comment: Works great and not just for this project. I made a minor addition to add an identifier like `'identifier_' + fn + '.pickle'` and change the identifier for my different calculations/programs. This avoids accidentally overwriting files.